# Preventing tabbing on some controls inside a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that has multiple `UserControls` in it.

When a button inside a user control is pressed, it will open and add another user control contaning a
text box and 2 buttons.

As soon as this user contorl is opened, the focus/cursor goes to the text box.

Pressing TAB button takes focus from one control to another, moving all through the form.

So basically I want to avoid this scenario.

i.e, there is a `UserControl` object called XXX. Now when I click "Open Edit" button in it, it opens a new `UserControl` object called YYY inside XXX.

`UserControl` YYY has a text box and 2 (Save & Cancel) buttons.

**I want to make sure that tabbing keeps the focus always
inside YYY until YYY is closed by clicking the Cancel button.**

I am not sure whether there's a form wide `TabStop` property? Or should i have to loop through other controls
and set it's `TabStop` to FALSE?

Considering that there're many other UserControls under different classes, it's kinda tedious.

Is there a easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Given your situation I will control the Tabbing through those newly created controls. You said that there are only a couple of entries created, so just start on the first control and on the second control (or last one) set the next control to have focus to the first one inside XXX. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: But what should happen if the user choose the mouse to set the focus on the tab-forbidden controls?

Comment: Well, these changes should only apply for keyboard accessibility. If user forces with mouse, that should be fine.

Comment: Very unlikely that this is practical for you, but WPF has the ability to cycle tabs within a usercontrol. You can open WPF forms from a winforms app. But depending on how far into the project you are it might be easier to track focus and enable/disable tabstops.

Comment: You can override [`ProcessTabKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.processtabkey(v=vs.110).aspx) and keep the tab in your control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually your question is:

**How to keep tab stop in a user control?**

You can override [`ProcessTabKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.processtabkey?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) in your  user control that you want to keep the tab stop.

```
protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward)
{
    return this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
}
```

This way, the tab stop will remain in your user control.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the `TabStop` property of each control to `False`.

You can do this either:

1. through the Designer
2. with code (possibly in the `Form_Load` event handler) for specific controls
3. with a recursive function for *mostly* all controls.

Naïve recursive function:
*I write in VB, so you'll need to translate*

```
Public Sub LoopControls()   '  Assumes this function lives within the scope of a Form
    LoopControls(Me)
End Sub  

Public Sub LoopControls(ByVal container As Control)
    '
    '  TODO:  Do something with the current control (container)
    '

    '
    '  Loop over the current control's inner controls
    '
    If Not Nothing Is container.Controls
        For Each control As Control In container.Controls
            LoopControls(control)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First 2 options are out of question as the form controls are loaded dynamically and there's no designer used. My original thinking was in favor of a recursive function that will go through all controls in the form and set TabStop to false, and when Cancel button is pressed, go back and set it back to true. Do you have any sample code that will show how to loop through all controls in a form?

Comment: Sure, there's a sample.

Comment: Thanks. Above answer worked. I will still give you a +1.